# Tkinter canvas (FigureCanvasTkAgg) bbox gives None

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Met strange problem : `canvas.bbox('ALL')` gives `None`.

SO topics say that `canvas` only have coords to give when there some is `.create_xxx()` methods in code. The thing is that class `FigureCanvasTkAgg` in its `__init__` method use `create_image` method and I think in my little snippet, when I create instance of thic Class it should give me some coordinate box when call `instance.bbox` command. But it's not...

```
self.Frame = Frame(root, bg = 'white')

self.Frame.place (relx = 0.37 , rely = 0.05 , relheight = 0.85 , relwidth = 0.51)

self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg ( fig , master = self.Frame)  # A tk.DrawingArea.

self.canvas.get_tk_widget ().place ( relx = 0 , rely = 0)


self.canvas.get_tk_widget ().config ( yscrollcommand = self.vbar.set ,
                                      scrollregion = (0,0,w,639*h/10 ))

self.canvas.get_tk_widget ().update_idletasks ()


print(self.canvas.get_tk_widget ().winfo_width(),self.canvas.get_tk_widget ().winfo_height() )
self.Frame.update_idletasks ()

print(self.canvas.get_tk_widget ().bbox('ALL'))
self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk ( self.canvas , self.Frame )

self.vbar.pack ( side = RIGHT , fill = Y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Met strange problem : canvas.bbox('ALL') gives None.

When you use `'ALL'`, it is looking for all canvas objects with the tag `'ALL'` and not finding any.

If you want the bounding box of all objects, the correct argument to `bbox` is `'all'`, not `'ALL'`. The literal string "all" is treated as a special case by the canvas to represent all objects on the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

@BryanOakley 's answer is really an important clarification.

The [excellent documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas-methods.html) by the late John Shipman, unfortunately, does have an error for present-day tkinter. It stated that:

```
.bbox(tagOrId=None)

Returns a tuple (x1, y1, x2, y2) describing a rectangle that encloses all the objects 
specified by tagOrId. If the argument is omitted, returns a rectangle enclosing all objects
on the canvas. The top left corner of the rectangle is (x1, y1) and the bottom right corner
is (x2, y2).
```

Presently, if `canvas.bbox()` is used, tkinter returns `_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!xxxxxxx bbox tagOrId ?tagOrId ...?"`

There are online tkinter documents that advocate using `ALL`. An example is this [one](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/other/python/0596001886_pythonian-chp-16-sect-7.html). However, most readers would have been oblivious that the `from tkinter import *` statement had been used to import all tkinter objects, which is also not in line with PEP8 guidelines on `import` statements. A good practice for importing tkinter is to use `import tkinter as tk`. Following this, your statement should either be:

```
print(self.canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox(tk.ALL))
```

or

```
print(self.canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox('all'))
```

**Summarising:** Either use `.bbox(tk.ALL)` or `.bbox('all')` on a `tk.Canvas` object/instance.